# MySQL: Cumulative sum of seconds between consecutive dates

Tags: mysql

I'm trying in every way to solve this problem. I have a table with a column giving ID (NOT auto increment) and another one with TIMESTAMP data as you can see in the image.

[Here is the table (table name: t_serie)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPjLW.png)

I want to calculate the cumulative sum of the difference in seconds between the date in a row and the date in row+1 through all the table.

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.time, t2.time)) as total
FROM t_serie AS t1 INNER JOIN t_serie as t2 ON t2.id = t1.id +1
```

That's the query I'm using but it doesn't work since the id column isn't an auto increment value. How can I do this without using ALTER TABLE or adding a new column using auto increment id?

Thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the `id` column of the table with next greater id. 
So joining on minimum of all the `ids` greater than current `id` should do it.

I think the below query should work for you.

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.time, t2.time)) as total
FROM t_serie AS t1 
INNER JOIN t_serie as t2 
ON t2.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM t_serie t3 where t1.id < t3.id);
```

Comment: I thought that query would work but it gets only the rows where rownumber = rownumber +1 like in the query I'm using... But still can't figure out the reason why this happens!

Comment: May be i can help if you tell me what exactly is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

For each `time`, you can use a subquery to check what would be the next `time` in the sequence. Then calculate the difference in seconds.

```
SELECT 
    time_a,
    time_b,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time_a, time_b) as difference_in_seconds
FROM (
    SELECT 
        `time` AS time_a,
        (
            SELECT      `time`
            FROM        t_serie b 
            WHERE       b.time > a.time
            ORDER BY    b.time asc
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS time_b
    FROM t_serie a
) tmp
```